# Memory in a char[]

Tags: c++, arrays

So I was working in c++ 11 and this occurred to me:

```
char s[100];
strcpy(s, "Andrei");
int n=strlen(Andrei); // (it would be 6)
```

I do this:

```
s[n]='  '; 
s[n+9]='\0';
```

What happens with s[n+1], ...  s[n+8]?
If I go

```
cout <<s;
```

The array will be displayed as normal.

But if I specify

```
cout <<s[n+2]
```

it will print odd characters

Comment: Are there supposed to be two spaces in `s[n]='  ';`? (they aren't being displayed in this comment for some reason).

Comment: `>>(it would be 6)`no it wouldn't unless `Andrei` is a variable containing "Andrei"

Comment: For any null-terminated byte string (like `s` in your example) then `s[strlen(s)]` will be the null terminator. Going beyond that leads to *undefined behavior*

Comment: Since you didn't initialize the contents of the array, and only assigned the first 7 bytes, the values in the rest of it it could be anything.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is no problem going beyond the null terminator if you initialized those elements (which didn't happen here).

Comment: @Ron Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Ron I see no such thing in the code supplied

Comment: @Ron What typo, the fact that he forgot to add `"` or the fact that it should have been `int n=strlen(s);`

Comment: @KillzoneKid My bad. Lack of MCVE makes it a guessing game. I have removed my comments.

Comment: @Ron No worries, this was poorly presented question, better to ignore those ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array elements `s[n+1]` ...  `s[n+8]` are uninitialized. They are said to have *indeterminate value*. Trying to output an indeterminate value causes undefined behaviour which means anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a buffer of 100 chars. Due the fact there is no strict initialization policy in C++, you got a buffer of BIG SOMETHING. Content of that "big something" would differ between each app launch, may vary on different build modes (debug/release) etc. Indeed, querying that "something" is like trying to listen a radio on a random wave and hear a noise sequence in return (it could be different each time you do this).

Running your strcpy would initialize just first N chars, the rest of the buffer is still "something".